# Manipulating variables in an activity with a method in another class

Tags: android, variables, methods, dynamic-variables

I am working on a game and have run into some issues. My architecture is something like this:

class GameView is used to draw bitmaps on my surfaces 
class GameLoopThread is used to implement my game loop (if it wasn't obvious...)
class MovementUtils is used to hold all of my utilities related to moving objects

I want to house methods like gravity and movement controls in MovementUtils, but I'm having trouble actually updating the values in GameView. I tried using an intent, to no avail. I'll post my code, and maybe someone can show me what I should do. Also, ignore the Accelerometer lines, that's another problem entirely...

GameView.java

```
package com.example.connorgame;


import java.util.EventObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class GameView extends SurfaceView  {
private Bitmap platform;
private Bitmap character;
private Bitmap background;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private MainActivity mainactivity;
private MovementUtils moveutil;

public float charX = 0;
public float charY = 0;
private boolean isFalling = true;
private boolean isJumping = false;
private float initialJumpY = 0;

private int initialFrame;
private int currentFrame;
private int frameDifference;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    mainactivity = (MainActivity) context;
    moveutil = new MovementUtils();

    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });



    platform = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.platform);
    character = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.character);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);

}



    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(platform, 30, 700, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(character, charX, charY, null);

        moveutil.gravity(charY, isFalling);

        if (charY > getHeight() - character.getHeight()) {
            initialFrame = gameLoopThread.numFrames;
            initialJumpY = charY;
            isFalling = false;
            isJumping = true;
        }

        if (isJumping == true && isFalling == false) {
            currentFrame = gameLoopThread.numFrames;
            frameDifference = (currentFrame - initialFrame);
            charY = charY - 5;

            if (charY == initialJumpY - 100) {
                isJumping = false;
                isFalling = true;
            }

        }

    }
```

}

MovementUtils.java

```
package com.example.connorgame;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MovementUtils {


public void gravity (float charY, boolean isFalling) {
    if(isFalling == true){
        charY = charY + 5;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, you're trying to have charY in the `GameView` class modified by the gravity function. The issue is that `float` is a primitive, so it is based by value and only the local copy will be modified. If you passed an object instead, the object would be modified.

One solution is probably to just return the new Y position instead of trying to make `gravity()` change the Y position.

Another solution is to pass the `GameView` to `MovementUtils` and let `MovementUtils` modify it.

In other words, you would pass the GameView like this `new MovementUtils(this);`

And the gravity function would call a `void setCharY(int y);` in GameView.

```
public class MovementUtils {
    private GameView gameView;

    public MovementUtils(GameView view) {
        this.gameView = view;
    }

    public void gravity (float charY, boolean isFalling) {
        if(isFalling == true){
            charY = charY + 5;
            gameView.setCharY(charY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I had already been doing this successfully by just applying my "gravity" in the GameView class, but I was trying to organize. I don't know why I didn't think of this. Btw, you wouldn't happen to know anything about accelerometer usage would you?

Comment: Glad this helped. I haven't worked with the accelerometer before, but I know there are lots of tutorials online.

Comment: Well, it's not so much an issue with the actual sensor, as it is declaring the object. I already have the constructor set up so that I can register the sensor in my mainactivity, but I also had to redo the constructor to allow me to change values in movementutils. I still need to be able to access accelerometerUtil class in my main activity though, and I don't know how to make the object usable.

Comment: @vulgarknight It might be a good idea to open a new question for this, as long as you show that you've put some effort into figuring it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Java only supports `passing by value`

So when you call `moveutil.gravity(charY, isFalling);`

and change it within the function, e.g.

```
public void gravity (float charY, boolean isFalling) {
if(isFalling == true){
    charY = charY + 5;
}
```

Such change **only** occur in the local copy of the variable `charY` and does **not** affect the instance variable `charY` defined in your `GameView` class

To solve this, you can define your variables as objects as well as the argument to your functions, e.g.

```
public void gravity (Float charY, boolean isFalling) {}
```

And in your GameView class:

```
private Float charX = 0; // why you define them public !?
private Float charY = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can pass an instance of your `GameView` class or create a `ValueObject` class (similar to `Context` object in android) and use it to pass arguments